# libgdx understanding coordinates system of scene2d actor

Tags: libgdx

plz I want to understand coordinates system of scene2d actor:

- localToDescendantCoordinates
- localToAscendantCoordinates
- localToParentCoordinates
- localToStageCoordinates
- parentToLocalCoordinates
- screenToLocalCoordinates
- stageToLocalCoordinates

note : explanation with examples and screenshots

Comment: I don't see a question here. You are looking for information which can be found in the [docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html#localToDescendantCoordinates-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-).

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no Question, but you can find the documentation here:
[libGDX Documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html)

These methods are transformations between the different coordinate systems.